# caches.keys is empty, although there are cached endpoints

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, caching, responsecache

I have an ajax endpoint that is cached (devtools > network shows it as (disk cache) - top of the image)
Yet, when I try to list all cached endpoints in the browser, I get an empty array (bottom of the image)

```
caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {console.log(keyList)});
```

What am I missing here?

I am trying to work an invalidation technique for asp.net core's [ResponseCache]

[image]

Comment: what cache are you running .open on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/keys#examples

Comment: uhm... none =) I am simply using the [ResponseCache] attribute from ASP.NET-Core controller. Thought it was the same (browser cache)